# Segue from AlertController without action

Tags: ios

I have a loading indicator, implemented with UIAlertController. When i send auth request to server - i fire up loading indicator. When request is successful i have to go to another ViewController and hide loading indicator. Before i perform segue i need to wait until AlertController dismiss indication is completed. So i have such a logic:

```
private var loadingIndicator: UIAlertController?

func navigateToMonitoring() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            if let indicator = self.loadingIndicator {
                while !indicator.isBeingDismissed { continue }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Monitoring", sender: self)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But when this method executed i've got a message - Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy! - and segue does not performed.

How can i fix this?

(Swift 3, Xcode 8)

Comment: **Don't wait!** These kind of repeat loops are horrendous. Use the completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe create the alert and store its reference, then show the alert and call the API, and in that API's completion block, you can dismiss it and perform the segue, hope this makes sense to you.